# WINAPI determine if specific SCSI device is present

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm currently trying to detect if a machine has a specific NVME SSD installed. On my machine, the file name is: `SCSI#Disk&Ven_NVMe&Prod_XPG_SPECTRIX_S40#5&1363da6c&0&000000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}`

What would be a reliable way to detect this universally on any machine? I don't know if any of these fields are unique to each machine, and I'm not very familiar with Windows' API.

Comment: *{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}* this is [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-disk) and will be the same on any windows, *SCSI#Disk&Ven_NVMe&Prod_XPG_SPECTRIX_S40* is also unique part. you can found this by [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_listw) with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`

Comment: also you can find this string by enumerate `\GLOBAL??` directory

Answer (score 0):

when disk type hardware is detected, kernel create device for it (really 2 device usually  *PDO* and *FDO* attached to it) and register well known interface [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-disk) (by call [`IoRegisterDeviceInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-ioregisterdeviceinterface) ). as result Symbolic Link will be created under `\GLOBAL??` directory. we can got all registered disk interfaces via [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_listw).

*SCSI#Disk&Ven_NVMe&Prod_XPG_SPECTRIX_S40#* obvious unique and will be the same anywhere for this device.

so code can be next

```
CONFIGRET Is_XPG_SPECTRIX_S40_Present(PBOOL pb)
{
    CONFIGRET cr;
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb;
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PZZWSTR Buffer;
    };
    static volatile UCHAR guz = 0;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    do 
    {
        cr = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW(&rcb, const_cast<GUID*>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK), 0, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);

        if (cr != CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (cb < (rcb *= sizeof(WCHAR)))
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);// /RTCs must be off
        }

        cr = CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(const_cast<GUID*>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK), 
            0, Buffer, cb, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);

    } while (cr == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

    if (cr == CR_SUCCESS)
    {
        while (*Buffer)
        {
            if (wcsstr(Buffer, L"\\SCSI#Disk&Ven_NVMe&Prod_XPG_SPECTRIX_S40#"))
            {
                *pb = TRUE;
                break;
            }
            Buffer += wcslen(Buffer) + 1;
        }
    }

    return cr;
}
```